# google search error

Tags: python, search, urllib2

I don't understand why this code works:

```
import urllib2 

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&q=voiture').read() 
print url
```

and not this one :

```
import urllib2 

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&q=voiture&start=2&sa=N').read() 
print url
```

it displays the following error:

```
**urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Google doesn't want you using their search engine like that, and they have lots of smart engineers figuring out how to stop you. FWIW, I get 403 for the first one too.

Comment: You might consider spoofing your headers and see if that gets you different results.

Comment: thank you for these answers , but if google forbidden this , is illegal ?

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work:import urllib2

url = 'http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&q=voiture&search=2&sa=N' 
opener = urllib2.build_opener(url) 
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')]
data = opener.open(url).read() 
print data

Comment: If you want legal advice, ask a lawyer. In some jurisdictions it's possible that circumventing a protection like that might be against the law. In any case, it's certainly bad practice to ignore any site's robots.txt, and you shouldn't be at all surprised if Google's systems start throwing up CAPTCHAs or just block your IP altogether if you're too persistant.